# Javascript / jQuery change inline style values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

I have an inline css in my page:

```
<style id="abc">
 .player-holder{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
 }
 .icon-color{
    color:#fff;
   -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out; 
 }
 .icon-rollover-color{
   color:#fff;
   -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out; 
 }
</style>
```

Is it possible to change some values on the fly (using jquery/javascript) so that browser takes change immediately?

Like change:

> .icon-rollover-color

to

> color:#333;

Comment: Search for `document.stylesheets`. There are lots of examples of doing different things with it.

Comment: That's not inline CSS .. that is internal css and you can override that with inline styles setted by Jquery like `$('.icon-rollover-color').css('color','red')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change inline CSS using the jquery .css() function. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/5dmzhqnp/).

```
$('p').css('color','#00FF00');
```

If you are dynamically adding elements then I would suggest you write this as a function that is called whenever a new element is added, probably using an event listener, that you can pass your updated style values to as parameters. Something like:

```
updateDOMStyle('<style>','<value>');
```

Answer (score 1):

in jquery

```
<script>

  $('.icon-rollover-color').css({
    'color': '#333'
  });

</script>
```

in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementByClassName(".icon-rollover-color").style.color="#333"
</script>
```

Comment: That only affects the elements currently on the page. If you add new elements dynamically, or change classes, they'll use the style from the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using simple jquery.

`$('.icon-rollover-color').css('color','red')`

Answer (score 0):

You, indeed this is possible!

Just add via Javascript or jQuery the following `style`-tag on the bottom of your page.

```
<style type="text/css">
.icon-rollover-color {
    color:#333!important;
}
</style>
```

You can add such codes to the bottom before the `body`-tag closes with the `append`-command:

```
$(body).append('<style type="text/css">.icon-rollover-color {color:#333!important;}</style>');
```